# PHP usort speed

Tags: php, sorting, usort

At first, I'll give a link to code: http://ideone.com/6k8R6
On my Intel Core 2 Duo, PHP 5.4.6 result is:
`usort: 7.8763520717621`
`quicksort: 2.9220938682556`
(`usort` is slower than `quicksort`)
But on Ideone result is:
`usort: 0.0313699245453`
`quicksort: 0.0621209144592`
(`usort` is faster than `quicksort`)
I have also checked code at my friend's computer (Intel Core i5, PHP 5.4.4), and `usort` was also faster.

My question is: why sometimes quicksort is faster than usort and sometimes usort is faster?

Comment: I suspect it's because you're using a really small dataset on ideone and that you have implemented quicksort in pure PHP, while usort is a library function.

Comment: I believe this is actually based upon the CPU due to Parallelization, I remember reading something about this somewhere....hmmm, I think it was wikipedia actually: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort but my head would hurt agian to read that through.

Comment: To add to that - your data set is four items. That's not even enough to properly demonstrate quicksort!

Comment: @duskwuff: my mistake, I have tried also on larger data set, but I pasted wrong link.

Comment: Tried it with a 20k dataset, on a first gen i7, PHP5.5.3 and I can not confirm that quicksort would be faster, on the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort is considered one of the fastest sort algorithms on unsorted data, and the slowest on already sorted (or nearly sorted) data.

Comment: Code was the same on each computer and function `set($uzytkownik);` used to set array to unsorted state before every sorting (I apologize for any grammatical errors, but I'm from Poland and it's quite late for me ;)).